# change url text in chrome address bar by chrome extension without actual navigating to it

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When user browses a webpage like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), is it possbile to change text in address bar to something like **[trusted]https://www.google.com** by chrome extension? Of course we wont browse to new text because it is not a valid url actually.

Comment: No. The address bar can only display the URL.

Comment: i see, not good to me but it makes sense.